# KOMA-Script: Adding "linebreak" after paragraph and subparagraph

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

I have the following example code:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrbook}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
Test

\section{Section}
Test

\subsection{SubSection}
Test

\subsubsection{SubSubSection}
Test

\paragraph{Paragraph}
Test

\subparagraph{SubParagraph}
Test

\end{document}
```

> I a looking for a clean KOMA solution to have the same **look/linebreak**
>   of **Paragraph** and **SubParagraph** **as** the **SubSubSection**.

AFAIK `titlesec` is not recommended together with KOMA script. Maybe `scrlayer-scrpage` is the way to go?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `afterskip` for `paragraph` and `subparagraph` to a positive value using:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  afterskip=1sp
]{paragraph,subparagraph}
```

Note that `1sp` is the smallest possible positive value.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrbook}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  afterskip=1sp
]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
Test
\section{Section}
Test
\subsection{SubSection}
Test
\subsubsection{SubSubSection}
Test
\paragraph{Paragraph}
Test
\subparagraph{SubParagraph}
Test
\end{document}
```